# Filter JSON data arduino

Tags: json, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to filter JSON data with my Arduin (working with an ESP8266). 
This is what I have :

```
if (httpCode > 0) {
  // Parsing
  const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(8) + 370;
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(http.getString());
  // Parameters
  int id = root["Reismogelijkheid"];
  const char* departure = root["ActueleVertrekTijd"];
  // Output to serial monitor
  Serial.print("Vertrijktijd:");
  Serial.println(departure);
}
```

I can make connection to my wifi network and I can make connection to the website to get JSON data from here : http://hendriks.pm/ns.php but I want to filter the data and only get the *ActueleVertrekTijd*, so that I can store it in a const and that I can see it on my Serial monitor.

I tried to use this example : https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Parsing-JSON/ but that didn't worked for me.

This is the Json :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow,

The problem is that you dont traverse trough the JSON.
If you want to retreive a value of an Object you should use

`root["Reismogelijkheid"]["ActueleVertrekTijd"]`

or if it is consistent:

`root["Reismogelijkheid"][5]`

instead of

`root["Reismogelijkheid"]`

This will give you the value that you want.

**EDIT**

For more information about parsing JSON you can use this site:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/decoding-and-encoding-json-with-arduino-or-esp8266/